# Wordpress media library don't show files manually added in upload folder

Tags: wordpress, file-upload, localhost

I'm very new to Wordpress. I just started working locally (using XAMPP on Ubuntu 14.04) when my HD crashed and i had to reinstall everything.
I'm pretty sure that before crash i was able to "upload" media simply by moving files into `upload` folder using a file manager (i'm sure i also added an `upload/bg` subfolder using shell). To see the new files into the media library i just had to refresh the media-upload page.

Now, after startover (ubuntu 16.04, lamp instead of XAMPP, WP 4.5.3 - can't remember old version) i cannot see copied media files anymore in media library.
Of course files are there (in the upload folder), both uploaded and copied, and i can see them using any browser (url like localhost/mysite/wp-content/uploads/myimg.jpg is working fine), but in media library i only see the uploaded ones.

Maybe in my old setting i installed a plugin that i forgot?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know:

WordPress stores all uploaded images in the wp-content/uploads folder in sub-folders for each month. **It also stores a unique reference to the uploaded image in the WordPress database.**

Comment: well, that's what's happening now, but i'm quite sure i didn't need to upload new images to see them... maybe there was a plug-in from some theme i tried?

Comment: No, if it was a plug-in, it was a non interactive process at all. Well, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can install a media file manager plugin
such as WP File Manager

But be care about it after install. It can modify all of your files (even out of uploads folder) and if an user (or hacker) can get high permission, it will be so dangerous.